# How the fee of ETF VTI is calculated?

Tags: etf, fees

For the ETF [VTI](https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/fees/vti),

> [image]

I tried to calculate the fee, but my number doesn't match that $71.

Here is my calculation:

[image]

Am I missing anything? The total fee the way I calculated is $45.57.

The formulas I am using are:

```
Balance: =10000 * POWER(1.09, A2-1)
Fee: =B2*0.0003
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have only 9 years of growth listed in your chart, not 10.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks. I think I should add another year and calculate the sum of fees starting from year 2, so the sum is $49.68.

Comment: You forgot to subtract the fee from the balance... you will not get 9% growth on the portion you had to pay out in fees.  Doing that, I get fees paid of $42.52, but the "cost" of the fee is $58.57.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might have been an oversight by someone at the company, but I got the number by doing this

`10,000 * POWER(1.09, 10) * 0.0003 * 10 = $71.02`

Which is incorrect because the fee will have less value early on (as you have shown in your table) but it gets you to the $71 that they are advertising.

---

**EDIT:**

After digging into it some more, Vanguard has cut the VTI expense ratio a few times. Looking at this [investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/news/vanguard-it-again-more-fee-cuts-vti-voo/) article they say that the expense ratio was dropped from 0.05% to 0.04% (and obviously it dropped again from 0.04% to 0.03%). Also in this this [blog](https://www.bogleheads.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=283598) they say that the overall expense ratio was 0.046%.  Doing the same math as you were doing with both of these ratios gives the following

0.04% gives a $60.77 fee

[image]

0.046% gives a $70.65 fee

[image]

0.05% gives a $70.96 fee (excluding the expense for year 1)

[image]

So my guess is Vanguard cut their expense ratio but didn't update this comparison of how little their fees were compared to their competitors.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you. That explained how $71 is calculated. And I agree with you, the total fees should be less than $71.

Comment: @zs2020 I found more information and updated my answer.